# Why don't we have distance lines on a Skoda reversing camera?

Tags: skoda, backup-camera

We just got ourselves a new Skoda Superb with a reversing camera but it doesn't show the distance lines that apparently should appear on it.

We test drove the Passat and saw [it had distance lines on it](http://www.satnavsystems.com/main/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/Reversing-camera-2Optional-RNS-510-Navigation-System.jpg) and [the Skoda manual also shows distance lines on the reversing camera](http://ws.skoda-auto.com/OwnersManualService/Data/en/Superb_3T/11-2014/Navigation/Columbus/B6_Superb_Columbus_NavigationSystem.pdf) but our new car doesn't show them – and I may be noobing it up, but I can't find any reference in the manual as to how to turn them on.

Any help at all would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can turn them on/off using the touch stuff found on page 38 of the manual you gave a link to. Here is an excerpt from it:

[image]

Looking at Figure 15 (on the left), it says to change the display to use **G** (bottom right hand corner of the display), which then flips you over to Figure 16 (on the right). Then try using **A** (upper left) on this screen or possibly **B** (upper right). If all else fails, you can look in the *Vehicle Owner's Manual*, in the chapter *Assistance Systems*. You might also try turning the camera off (**G**), then back on again. This may reset the camera and settings to factory standard.

Comment: Pressing **A** turns on **F**.  Pressing **B** shows **G, H, I and J**.  No luck so far - we'll probably have to contact the dealer.