# VW Touran MK2 2023 rear camera guide lines

Tags: vw, backup-camera

During parking I don't see yellow guide lines in the rear camera view. I'm not sure if it should be visible or not. Could somebody confirm that behavior please?

Answer (score 0):

[This non-VW website](https://www.vwtouran.net/introduction-278.html) says "A camera in the tailgate helps the driver when reversing or manoeuvring the vehicle. The camera picture and the orientation lines projected by the system are displayed on the screen of the factory-fitted radio or navigation system."

Comment: yup, I read the owners manual but it does not describe many details. IIRC demo car had questioned feature, my does not. That is why I am asking

Comment: If you drove a demo at the dealer, ask them. It's also possible that the orientation lines are turned off on your car; see [this question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/14943/why-dont-we-have-distance-lines-on-a-skoda-reversing-camera?rq=1) about a Skoda vehicle with a similar issue.